# Can't connect from docker using mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I'm trying to connect to my mysql container but whenever I try to run `mysql -uroot -p` I always get `bash: mysql: command not found` but mysql is already installed in the docker container when I try to run `pip3 freeze` I get this result

```
alembic==0.9.6
appdirs==1.4.3
bcrypt==3.1.4
certifi==2017.11.5
cffi==1.11.2
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
elasticsearch==5.5.1
flasgger==0.8.0
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
gevent==1.2.2
greenlet==0.4.12
idna==2.6
iso3166==0.8
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
mistune==0.8.3
mock==2.0.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
packaging==16.8
pbr==3.1.1
pybuilder==0.11.12
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-editor==1.0.3
PyYAML==3.12
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.0
tblib==1.3.2
ujson==1.35
urllib3==1.21.1
validate-email==1.3
Werkzeug==0.13
```

As you can see mysqlclient is installed. If I try to check if mysql container is accessible inside my docker using ping. It's working properly and I was able to get a response. How do I connect now since it says `bash: mysql: command not found`

-- UPDATE --

After running docker run I connected inside the docker container and run `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` and below is the output

[image]

Now it says requirement already satisfied. I'm not sure but does this mean it already installed the package? Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5.2
ADD deployment /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/myproject
CMD ["python", "./init.py", "-c", "config/config.yaml"]
```

Comment: but you have mysql-client installed on the host machine?

Comment: Yes. As you can see when running pip3 freeze it displays all packages that is installed in the host

Comment: what is output of: which mysql

Comment: Sorry my question was incorrect. I thought you were trying to access mysql from the host machine. Now maybe I am wrong but I think "mysql-client" can't be installed with pip, you'll have to install that separately into the system.

Comment: @FurhanS. there are no output.

Comment: @eLRuLL probably you're right. I tried running docker-compose and mysql client is being installed properly not sure why pip3 freeze won't install it

Comment: what system are you on? centos or debian or mac?

Comment: but are you running that command inside your docker container? or on your development machine?

Comment: @FurhanS. I'm running on mac but command of mysql is being run inside my docker container

Comment: @PekosoG I'm running it inside my docker container. I'm not sure what OS is it

Comment: @MadzmarUllang which image are you importing from DockerHub? how does your Dockerfile looks like?

Comment: @PekosoG updated my question

Comment: @MadzmarUllang there's the problem, you are using a Python image, not a MySQL.... The confusion here is that you are installing mysqlclient but that only the library/ORM that will allow you to connect from Python to a MySQL Server, that's not a MySQL Database Engine

Comment: @PekosoG I have my mysql instance in a separate container as mentioned on my question above. When trying to PING inside the python container to the mysql container I get a response back meaning connection successful. I just need to connect from my python container to the mysql container but I can't do that because mysql-client is not found

Comment: @MadzmarUllang i understand, but again, that mysqlclient library is only for Python using PIP, what you would need to do is install the actual MySQL client binaries directly to your container in order to use the bash command "mysql" BUT there's something, do you have exposed the port on the MySQL Container or will they both live inside a docker-compose network? You need to set that up before trying to connect

Comment: @PekosoG yup I exposed it with the mysql default port.

Comment: @MadzmarUllang then, in your dockerfile try add this line "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-client", once the container is running, get inside and try to connect using "> mysql -p -h <mysql-container>"

Comment: @PekosoG yeah it works but I'm receiving Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' when I navigate to that folder it does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162055/discussion-between-pekosog-and-madzmar-ullang).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the CLI command `mysql` is not installed on your HOST machine. It is most likely installed inside your docker container however. As one of the comments pointed out, the `mysqlclient` you installed with `pip` would NOT install the `mysql` command line tool.

As a quick workaround, I would suggest running the `mysql` command INSIDE your mysql container, like so:

```
docker exec -it <container id> mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```